# CA Agile Central Stories by Feature

Tags: html, rally

I have used the "Print Story Card" feature provided in the following GitHub link:

https://github.com/jkrooswyk/Print-Story-Cards-with-Mods-Apps/blob/master/Print%20All%20Backlog%20Story%20Cards.html.

However, I would like to modify it a bit to sort the stories by Feature, so that I can print the features on different colors of paper. Is there a way to modify this code to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just change this line:

https://github.com/jkrooswyk/Print-Story-Cards-with-Mods-Apps/blob/master/Print%20All%20Backlog%20Story%20Cards.html#L183

to something like this:

```
order: 'Feature'
```